# android localization resource chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I have an android application on eclipse it's  text-views and the    buttons' texts on Arabic language , I want to localize my application to both Arabic and English users .

Firstly under res folder I have created another folder and named it values-en .
I let the original folder values as is it and later I will use it for Arabic .

My first question it is necessary  to create  another folder (values-ar) for Arabic localization issues.
Or original values folder is just enough?.

Secondly
On values-en folder I   created  strings.xml file and  added the following statement to it
COMTAS

I set   the text of one of the textviews from resource chooser so   choose application-title .
after that the   textview's text converted to @string/application-title.

the project gives me the following message

NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
[image]

Can someone explains to me how to make localization in simple steps.
And how   I can retrieve textviews'  texts either in english or arabic (reading from values folder)?

Comment: First of all you can't define "-" as label in String.xml and for localization you have create separate values folder for both language,default language put in default values folder and for secondary language create another values folder with language code like values-ar or values-en.

Comment: Post the logcat. Also post the java code where you are setting the text for the TextView.

Comment: How can a button makes the app reads from values-en folder and another button reads from values-ar folder when it pressed . I need a code please

Answer (score 1):

First: Leaving a strings.xml in the "values" folder will cause this language to be "default" (or rather "fallback") language.

Second: The text is read automatically from the strings.xml placed in the values-folder matching your System Locale (the locale you get when you call `Locale.getDefault()`), e.g. if system locale is set to english, the values are taken from values-en folder. Therefore it would be wise to place the arabic values in a values-ar folder.

I can't say anything related to your compile errors as you didn't post the code causing the error.

Comment: I have knew my what was the error ,the error was the setting the text   of textview application-title not application_title

Comment: How can  a button  makes  the app   reads from values-en folder  and another button   reads from values-ar folder when it pressed .  
I need a code please

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to follow the documentation. Here is the link for [Localizing with Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Create a `values-ar` folder for the arabic language, and  let the default language as english. Why?

**Whenever the application runs in a locale for which you have not provided locale-specific text, Android will load the default strings from `res/values/strings.xml`.**

So if your application is running on a device set to **Spanish** language, it would still load arabic language (if it's set as default).

English is a most talked language, which would be better to let english by default, ant let the arabic language in `values-ar`(in my humble opinion).

Hope this helps you.